# Open/Close Dialog element, whenever I press specific button (F3)

Tags: c#, blazor

Tried "onkeydown" event in my dialog, and it worked only to close dialog when it was opened.

To be more general: I want to toggle element visibility with key, no matter where the focus is...

My friend (Front-end developer) gave me a tip. I have to use addEventListener() method and cast it on entire Window or document like:

```
document.addEventListener(event, eventHandler, useCapture)
```

Any idea how to make this in Blazor environment?

Comment: Just so you are aware, to bind to F3, you have to use "keydown" instead of "keypress" as it doesn't trigger "keypress"

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to see keypresss events in Blazor.
Add the following to some global js file accessable to your application: (Make sure you replace `YOUR_ASSEMBLY_HERE` with your assembly name!)

```
// Serialize the event for Blazor
function serializeEvent(e) {
    if (e) {
        var o = {
            key: e.key,
            code: e.code,
            location: e.location,
            repeat: e.repeat,
            ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
            shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
            altKey: e.altKey,
            metaKey: e.metaKey,
            type: e.type
        };
        return o;
    }
}

// Listen for keypress, and invoke method 'OnKeyPress'
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('YOUR_ASSEMBLY_HERE', 'OnKeyPress', serializeEvent(e))
});
```

Empty blazor component: (I just called mine Invokables.razor)

```
@code {
    [JSInvokable]
    public static async Task OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e){
        // Do some stuff here
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(e));
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I serialized the event as JSON in `OnKeyPress` so you can see it in the console as you're using it. Here's the console output from typing "tsce":

```
{"Key":"t","Code":"KeyT","Location":0,"Repeat":false,"CtrlKey":false,"ShiftKey":false,"AltKey":false,"MetaKey":false,"Type":"keypress"}
{"Key":"s","Code":"KeyS","Location":0,"Repeat":false,"CtrlKey":false,"ShiftKey":false,"AltKey":false,"MetaKey":false,"Type":"keypress"}
{"Key":"c","Code":"KeyC","Location":0,"Repeat":false,"CtrlKey":false,"ShiftKey":false,"AltKey":false,"MetaKey":false,"Type":"keypress"}
{"Key":"e","Code":"KeyE","Location":0,"Repeat":false,"CtrlKey":false,"ShiftKey":false,"AltKey":false,"MetaKey":false,"Type":"keypress"}
```

Comment: Code seems to be incomplete. It did nothing in Blazor web app - no console output. I dont see where is JS Function called in your example.

Comment: @ErikZámečník I wrote it, tested it, and then posted it. It is possible you didn't replace the "YOUR_ASSEMBLY_HERE" with the name of your assemble or your javascript is not being delivered. See this for more documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-8.0#invoke-a-static-net-method